# Upgrading grails 2 to grails 3: HibernateCriteriaBuilder equivalent

Tags: grails, grails-2.3, grails-3.1

I am upgrading several plugins and one application from grails 2.3.11 to grails 3.1.10 right now. 
In some places I have encountered

```
    import grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder
```

Which does not exist in Grails 3. 
Is

```
    import grails.gorm.CriteriaBuilder;
```

The right replacement?

EDIT1: Grails 3.1 documentation suggests that grails.orm is still part of the distribution: http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html but plugin created with grails create-plugin and default gradle build file does not have it.

Comment: What happens if you change the import. Does query work ? Some grails docs do get outdated